# ANTLR4.7 listener for a rule when sub rules are labeled

Tags: antlr4

I have an `antlr4.7` grammar like this, where all sub rules are labeled.

```
date_expr
    :   attr op=( '+' | '-' ) dt_interval=ISO8601_INTERVAL
        #dateexpr_Op
    |   DATETIME_NAME
        #dateexpr_Named
    |   d=( DATETIME_LITERAL | DATE_LITERAL | TIME_LITERAL ) 
        #dateexpr_Literal
    |   attr
        #dateexpr_Attr
    |   '(' date_expr ')'
        #dateexpr_Paren
    ;
```

I would like to annotate the tree when a `date_expr` rule completes. However, looking at the generated listener class, I see no `exitDate_expr`. How can I add this? Or, do I have to use a visitor interface for it. I am not much familiar with grammar tools.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve `beforeAllLabledAlts` and `afterAllLabledAlts` visit points, wrap the labeled alt rule in a singleton rule:

```
anyDate : dateExpr ;
dateExpr
    :   attr op=( '+' | '-' ) dt_interval=ISO8601_INTERVAL    #dateexpr_Op
    |   DATETIME_NAME                                         #dateexpr_Named
    |   d=( DATETIME_LITERAL | DATE_LITERAL | TIME_LITERAL )  #dateexpr_Literal
    |   attr                                                  #dateexpr_Attr
    |   '(' date_expr ')'                                     #dateexpr_Paren
    ;
```

The ANTLR tool will then generate the listener interface (and/or visitor interface) with `AnyDateContext` `onEntry` and `onExit` methods.

Comment: to clarify, is this a common idiom? E.g. I have a dateExpr occuring in several contexts. To identify the context of a date part, either I traverse up the tree from exit of the date part - which means it has to know the kinds of parents, Or, use something like your illustration (where I would traverse the subtree). Thanks.