# ANTLR4: after adding alternative labels, can I label the original rule?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I added some alternative label as below. Now the parser methods are generated for `enterSomeType`, `enterSomeOtherType`. But How do I get a hold of the original type, i.e.: `enterType`

```
type
  : IDENTIFIER     # someType
  | typeDescriptor # someOtherType
  ;
```

Comment: Not directly. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46655157/antlr4-7-listener-for-a-rule-when-sub-rules-are-labeled/46657088#46657088).

Comment: @GRosenberg Still got question. Suppose I wrap `type` with a `baseType` rule. In my parser, when I get a `TypeContext` (using `baseTypeContext.type()`), how do I identify this `TypeContext` is a `SomeTypeContext` or `SomeOtherTypeContext`? This identification is needed because I need to pass in corresponding listeners.

Comment: The answer could be as simple as "instanceof".  But, it could also be, "use term labels instead of alt labels". Also, not sure what you mean by "I need to pass in corresponding listeners." Really should explain the full context of your question to get a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your question (language? time?).

In Python, when I traverse the tree (hence "child"):
`rule=str(parser.ruleNames[child.getPayload().getRuleIndex()])` gives the name of the rule (e.g., 'type')
`lbl=child.__class__.__name__[:-7]` gives the alternative label (e.g., 'SomeOtherType')